# How to create a List<Object>listName with XML?

Tags: mysql, xml, spring-boot, xsd

I have a database in MySQL which is connected through SpringBoot to my project to access the data and  I have annotations that I need to match in XML with the specific type of objects.

I need to make a List of objects from a complex type of object in XML. I can't figure out how I am supposed to do that.
(In the auto-generated MedicationPlanType class I need to have a List medicationsList parameter)

My Entity table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MedicationPlan")
public class MedicationPlan {
    /*One to Many mapping
     * idMedications
     * idPatient
     * Date of begining
     * Date of ending
     * IdMedPlan
     * */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idMedicationPlan", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int idMedicationPlan;

    @Column(name = "startDate")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "endDate")
    private Date endDate;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPatient", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private int patient;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Medication_idMedication", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        List<Medication> medicationsList;
```

I have tried to declare it as :

```
 <xs:complexType name="MedicationPlanType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id_MedicationPlan" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="starteDate" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="patient" type="tns:patientType" />
                <xs:element name="medicationsList" type="tns:medicationsList" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="MedicationType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="idmedication" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="medicationName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="dosage" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="sideEffects" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="intakeIntervals" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

         <xs:complexType name="medicationsList">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="medicationsList" type="tns:MedicationType" />
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
```

But this creates an instance of MedicationsList rather than a list. 
 I also tried:

```
    <xs:element name="medicationsList">
        <xs:list itemType="tns:MedicationType"/>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:complexType name="medicationsList">
        <xs:list itemType="tns:MedicationType"/>
    </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="medicationsList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:list itemType="tns:MedicationType"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

But  neither one seems to work.

Any help or a work-around this issue is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is tns:MedicationType a simple or a complex type? And what type of list do you mean? Some more proposals: [XSD](https://www.codepile.net/pile/Ya9egjaM) [XML](https://www.codepile.net/pile/MXWAj2m0)

Comment: MedicationType is a complex type defined above. Bassicaly, i want an arrayList<MedicationType >medicationsList to be automatically generated by the xml.